# read lines with while loop return not desired answer

Tags: bash

Example:

The file list.txt :

```
$ cat list.txt

/apps
/log
/data

$ for i in `cat list.txt`; do
>   ls -ld $i | awk '{print $3}'
> done

appuser1
appuser2
appuser3

$ for i in `cat list.txt`; do
>   ls -ld $i | awk '{print $3}'
> done | while read -r line ; do
>   printf "%s For Filesystem $i "
>   getent passwd $line | awk -F: '{print $5}'
> done

For Filesystem /data owner=User1
For Filesystem /data owner=User2
For Filesystem /data owner=User3
```

And the desired result should be :

```
For Filesystem /apps owner=User1
For Filesystem /log owner=User2
For Filesystem /data owner=User3
```

In reality the list.txt file is very long command that parsing /proc/mounts file from every server and this list needs to be redirected to while.

Comment: You are using your `for` loop control variable in the `while` loop but it isn't changing anymore there.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs. Also, try running your code through http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: ...but yes, what Etan gave is exactly the immediate cause of your problem (and what @TomFenech is suggesting is a good solution, as long as you're only targeting systems with GNU stat) -- you aren't running the while/read loop inside the for loop, so why would you expect `$i` to be appropriate for each line?

Comment: @Charles I'm glad you approve :) is there a more portable solution than to use `stat`?

Comment: @TomFenech, ...so, the mode, links and owner fields _are_ actually safe to parse from `ls -l` (but anything beyond that point -- the timestamp or filename -- is not, making it necessary to call `ls -ld "$file"` on a single file at a time, to already know the name, if you're doing it that way). But that's ugly and awful enough that relying on GNU stat (or GNU find with its `-printf`) tends to be very, very forgiveable. :)

Comment: @TomFenech, ...for other alternatives, see BashFAQ #87: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/087

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you change your script to something like this:

```
while read -r line; do 
    owner=$(stat -c"%U" "$line")
    echo "For Filesystem $line owner=$owner"
done < list.txt
```

The `while read` loop reads `list.txt` one line at a time. `stat` is used to provide information about a file or directory. The `-c` switch allows you to specify a format string for the output. `%U` is the username of the owner.

In general, you shouldn't be parsing `ls` and it is unnecessary to use `cat` in this case.

In response to your comments, if instead of using a file, you would like to pass the output of another process, you could do something like this:

```
while read -r line; do 
    owner=$(stat -c"%U" "$line")
    echo "For Filesystem $line owner=$owner"
done < <(awk '{print $2}' /proc/mounts)
```

There is no need to store the output of the other command in a variable. If you *wanted* to use a variable, you could use:

```
filesystems=$(awk '...' /proc/mounts)
```

before the loop, then either:

```
done <<<"$filesystems"        # less portable (works on bash)
```

or:

```
done < <(echo "$filesystems") # extra process, slightly longer
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, works perfect. But if I need to use except file name "awk from /proc/mounts" for filesystem list, how can I redirect it ?

Comment: Glad it works, I'm not sure I understand what you mean though. If it's something minor, you should edit your question to make it clear exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @user1607856, `done < <(awk ... </proc/mounts)`; note that the space is essential. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution for details.

Comment: Hi Charles, can I pass variable, like : FSNAMES=$(awk /prc/mounts) and then done < <($FSNAMES)?

Comment: @user1607856 Charles' suggestion was to pass the output of the process directly to the loop. You can use a variable instead if you want. I've edited my answer to explain more.

Comment: Have an issue when run this remotely on AIX ( as by default it's ksh ).

Comment: @user1607856 Unfortunately I can't test on ksh - you tagged the question bash which is why I answered :) Without knowing exactly what you're doing and what error you're getting, it's hard for me to say what the problem is. Perhaps you'd be better off asking a new question and seeing if someone with ksh can help.